# libtool version mismatch error

Tags: autotools, libtool

When building my application with kdevelop 3.5 on Ubuntu 10.04, I get the following errors:

```
libtool: Version mismatch error. This is libtool 2.2.6 Debian-2.2.6a-4, but the
libtool: definition of this LT_INIT comes from libtool 2.2.6b.
libtool: You should recreate aclocal.m4 with macros from libtool 2.2.6 Debian-2.2.6a-4
libtool: and run autoconf again.
make[2]: *** [wktools4] Error 63
make[2]: Target `all' not remade because of errors.
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
*** Exited with status: 2 ***
```

Where can I get the needed version of libtool, or how can I recreate aclocal.m4?

Answer (score 163, accepted):

Try running

```
autoreconf --force --install
./configure
make
```

in the root directory of your project.

If that doesn't work, try running `make maintainer-clean` first and then go to step 1.

If that still doesn't work, run `make maintainer-clean`, then delete every generated file in the root directory of your project; including `aclocal.m4`, any `m4` directory, any `autom4te.cache` directory, `configure`, `Makefile.in`, `config.h`, `config.h.in`, `config.status`, `libtool`, `ltmain.sh`, etc. Then go to step 1.

**Why this works:** `libtool` and `aclocal.m4` are both files that are generated by your build system. If they are out of sync (generated by different versions of the build tools), then you get this error. Normally that shouldn't happen, but an example of something that can cause it is when you check in generated files to source control.

What this solution does is delete and regenerate all the autogenerated files. Once they're erased and regenerated, they can't be out of sync anymore.

Comment: I don't want to edit the answer because I don't understand, but I had this error, and `autoreconf` wasn't enough. I had to run: `aclocal; libtoolize --force; autoheader; autoconf`

Comment: `autoreconf` does nothing else than run all those programs for you. It's probably a good idea to add the `--force` option though, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: I tried this with php5 on ubuntu 12.04, but things gone worse after this command: I'm not able to execute `./configure` successfully after this

Comment: If there's an `autogen.sh` or `bootstrap` script, run that first.

Comment: But why does this help?  What is the version mismatch really about?

Comment: @ptomato, thanks for your answer. I've stuck in similar issue. Could you, please, take a look at my question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28788920/libtool-issue-while-compile-liblinphone

Comment: Is it possible to specify the directory of the libtool version I want to use? How do I do that?

I am thinking like 

autoreconf --force --install <insert libtool version here>

Answer (score 14):

If you are using Anaconda, then this could be due to libtool and autoconf from different sources. You can check this by executing

`which libtool`

`which autoconf`

My libtool was from conda and autoconf was a system package. Uninstalled autoconf and installed it again using conda

`apt remove -y autoconf` (Ubuntu/Debian)

`conda install -c anaconda autoconf`

Note: You may need to install automake too.

`conda install -c anaconda automake`

Answer (score 12):

Try

```
autoreconf -i
```

The `-i` option is important.

Answer (score 3):

maybe you have installed two libtools of different version. Try to `apt-get remove all` (until you get nothing, when you type `which libtool` in the command line), then `apt-get install` the one you like.

Comment: Didn't realize this until I run which libtool and find that it points to my anaconda installation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try running aclocal

Comment: thank you for your answer. Could you please be more specific? Which options do I have to use? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solve that uninstalling system's libtool and installing from upstream: git clone git://git.savannah.gnu.org/libtool.git

```
sudo apt-get install texinfo autoconf automake make
./bootstrap
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked.

Then this worked:

```
autoconf -f
./configure
make
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked. After I deactivated the conda environment, it worked:

`source deactivate`

Answer (score 0):

I also encounter this issue. In my case, in the output of  ./autogen.sh, there is:

libtoolize: You should add the contents of the following files to    'aclocal.m4': libtoolize:   '/aclocal/libtool.m4' libtoolize:    '/aclocal/ltoptions.m4' libtoolize:   '/aclocal/ltversion.m4' libtoolize: Consider adding    'AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIRS([m4])' to configure.ac, libtoolize: and    rerunning libtoolize and aclocal. libtoolize: Consider adding '-I m4'    to ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS in Makefile.am.

I just append the content the three *.m4 files under /aclocal/ to the aclocal.m4 file:

```
cat <a path>/aclocal/libtool.m4 <a path>/aclocal/ltoptions.m4 <a path>/aclocal/ltversion.m4 >> aclocal.m4
```

then make.

Answer (score 0):

here is the error:

```
libtool: Version mismatch error.  This is libtool 2.4.2 Debian-2.4.2-1.11, but the
libtool: definition of this LT_INIT comes from libtool 2.4.6.
libtool: You should recreate aclocal.m4 with macros from libtool 2.4.2 Debian-2.4.2-1.11
libtool: and run autoconf again.
```

None of the above worked.

Then this worked:

```
wget http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/libtool/libtool-2.4.6.tar.gz -O /root/libtool-2.4.6.tar.gz
tar xzvf /root/libtool-2.4.6.tar.gz -C /root
cp -f /usr/share/libtool/build-aux/ltmain.sh /usr/share/libtool/build-aux/ltmain_sh
cp -f /root/libtool-2.4.6/build-aux/ltmain.sh /usr/share/libtool/build-aux/ltmain.sh

autoreconf -fi
./configure
make
```

Answer (score 0):

I also use custom include directories for autoconf and autoreconf, like `autoreconf -I ./m4`. So it happened that an outdated `ltversion.m4` accidentially was sitting inside one of those custom includes. This caused exactly the same error here. I solved it by removing the outdated `ltversion.m4` file.