# Install imagick on gentoo error

Tags: imagick, php-extension, pecl, libtool, gentoo

When i use this command `pecl install imagick` to install imagick for php i got this error message :

```
libtool: Version mismatch error.  This is libtool 2.2.6b, but the
libtool: definition of this LT_INIT comes from an older release.
libtool: You should recreate aclocal.m4 with macros from libtool 2.2.6b
libtool: and run autoconf again.
make: *** [imagick_file.lo] Erreur 63
```

I found the solution another question with the same error but different application install, but it still not working : [libtool version mismatch error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096989/libtool-version-mismatch-error)

How to fixed this, please ?

Answer (score 1):

This solution seems to fix this problem. Seen in [Bug #58979](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=58979)

```
wget http://pecl.php.net/get/imagick
tar xvzf imagick
cd ./imagick-3.2.0RC1
phpize
aclocal
libtoolize --force
autoheader
autoconf
./configure
make && make install
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an ebuild available. I'd give it a try:

```
$ eix imagick
* dev-php/pecl-imagick
     Available versions:  3.0.1-r1 3.1.0_rc2 ~3.1.2 ~3.2.0_rc1 {examples PHP_TARGETS="php5-3 php5-4 php5-5"}
     Homepage:            http://pecl.php.net/imagick
     Description:         PHP wrapper for the ImageMagick library.
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into the gentoo bugzilla if there's a bug report and try not to install packages from outside of portage as it tends to break stuff! Usually there are at least some hacks around to get the ebuild working.

If not, just give it a day or two...