# Libtool issue while compiling Liblinphone

Tags: ios, sip, autotools, libtool, speex

I'm trying to compile this lib:
 https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-iphone

During generation I get this:

```
/linphone-iphone/submodules/build/..//externals/speex/libspeex/cb_search.c
libtool: Version mismatch error.  This is libtool 2.4.6, but the
libtool: definition of this LT_INIT comes from libtool 2.4.2.
libtool: You should recreate aclocal.m4 with macros from libtool 2.4.6
libtool: and run autoconf again.
make[4]: *** [cb_search.lo] Error 63
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [build-speex] Error 2
make: *** [broadcast_all] Error 2
```

Ok, then, (as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096989/libtool-version-mismatch-error)) :

```
cd ../externals/speex/  
autoreconf --force --install

cd cd ../../build && make all
```

And... It happens again!
What's wring with **libtool**?

Answer (score 2):

After you run `autoreconf`, the appropriate `configure` script has to be executed. Until then, it the work `autoreconf` does is not effective.

Sometimes `make` recognizes this, but it may not be the case here.
Therefore I recommend you to run the top-level `configure` script (I assume that this is what you have ran at the beginning) and then resume building using `make all`.

You have probably hit a bug of how the software is distributed. If distributors think that they have to distribute the dependency as a sub-project of the software, they should take care that there are no discrepancies between `libtool` versions used.

Comment: Actually, I've not installed some dependancies. But there are new errors.