# Issue after make all in installing mongodb php7 driver ubuntu

Tags: php, mongodb, ubuntu, php-7

I'm trying to install mongodb php7 driver in ubuntu, when I clone the last source from github, I cd into the directory as the guide in php.net says, I phpize and then run `./configuration`, and yet there is neither error nor problem, put when I try to install in with `make all` and after that `sudo make install` I get strange error which is killing me and I don't know why it happens. (I get this error when I try to install it with `pecle install mongodb` too).
here is the error:

```
libtool: Version mismatch error.  This is libtool 2.4.2 Debian-2.4.2-1.11, but the
libtool: definition of this LT_INIT comes from libtool 2.4.6.
libtool: You should recreate aclocal.m4 with macros from libtool 2.4.2 Debian-2.4.2-1.11
libtool: and run autoconf again.
Makefile:205: recipe for target 'php_mongo.lo' failed
make: *** [php_mongo.lo] Error 63
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [libtool version mismatch error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096989/libtool-version-mismatch-error)

Comment: @titi23  can you please explain more ?

Comment: See the [link](http://www.howtodoityourself.org/how-to-fix-libtool-version-mismatch-error.html), which may help you solving the issue.

Comment: Click the first link and check answer of that question in stackoverflow.

Comment: @titi23  I checked both of them and tried everything they've said, unfortunately I still get the same error.